# C++ - QFileDialog opens additional non-handled windows

Tags: c++, qt

I have an issue using the static member functions of QFileDialog. When the file explorer dialog opens, another window is opened in background, but contains nothing : it isn't just painted. It closes when I select something and close the file dialog but it remains annoying.

I'd like to get rid of it. I read an existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557285/qfiledialog-opens-a-second-possibly-parent-unwanted-window/26077860) about this issue that suggested to give a parent for the dialog as argument to the function. So I used a very simple parent widget :

```
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(new QWidget(),trUtf8("Choose a file"));
```

And then I had no more one annoying window, but two. The first one was closed when I closed the file explorer dialog, but the second one remained until I closed the application.

I think the second window was the QWidget I gave as parent. The default value for the first argument is 0, but maybe Qt creates a QWidget() in this case.

I tried to create an independant QWidget and hide it before calling getOpenFileName() :

```
QWidget *w = new QWidget();
w->hide();
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(w,trUtf8("Choose a file"));
```

But it doesn't change anything, and I still get two unwanted windows. At last, I tried to use a QLabel as parent to see if it was really shown :

```
QLabel *l = new QLabel("Test");
QString str = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(l,trUtf8("Choose a file"));
```

But it seems it is not. Obviously nothing is handling those windows... they aren't just painted, when you move a window on them, you can see the trace it leaves.

I ran out of ideas... does anyone have any other idea to solve that annoying problem ?

Comment: That's odd, I'm using QT 4.8 and experiencing nothing on windows. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.3, and I remember that I had not this problem with Qt 4.8. This is also what was noticed in the thread I linked.

Comment: It might be a Qt bug..

Comment: Do not set the parent for the QFileDialog. I.e. QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, trUtf8("Choose a file"));

Comment: That's what I did first. This opens an additional window. Setting the parent opens a second window.

Comment: Please let us know *exactly* what compiler, what platform, what bitness, and what Qt version (x.y.z not merely x.y).

Comment: My compiler is g++ 4.8.2, working on a Linux Mint 16 64-bit (MATE). I'll edit later the Qt version because I'm not sure.